# Propositional Logic Identity

Tags: logic, algebra, truthtable

How to show that  ↔  ≡  ∨  → ( ∧ )

So far I've done this...

↔  ≡(p → q) ∧(q → p) Law of Algebra
(p → q) ∧ (q → p) ≡(~p V q) ∧ (q → p) Law of Conditional Proposition
(~p V q) ∧ (q → p) ≡(~p V q) ∧ (~q V p) Law of Conditional Proposition

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about logic and [math.se] instead of directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 4):

**By identity laws:**

```
p ↔ q                                  Given
(p → q) & (q → p)                      ↔ Elimination
(~p ∨ q) & (~q ∨ p)                   Material implication
((~p ∨ q) & ~q) ∨ (((~p ∨ q) & p))    Distributive
~p & ~q ∨ q & ~q ∨ ~p & p ∨ q & p     Distributive
~p & ~q ∨ F ∨ F ∨ q & p               Complement
~p & ~q ∨ q & p                       Identity
~(p ∨ q) ∨ p & q                      De Morgan's law
(p ∨ q) → (p & q)                     Material implication
```

**By natural deduction:**

To prove an identity by natural deduction, you have to conduct your proof in both directions. That is, you have to prove both that:

- p ↔ q entails (p ∨ q) → (p & q), and
- (p ∨ q) → (p & q) entails p ↔ q

```
{1}    1.  p ↔ q                          Prem.
{1}    2.  (p → q) & (q → p)              1 ↔E
{1}    3.  p → q                          2 &E
{1}    4.  q → p                          2 &E
{5}    5.  p ∨ q                          Assum.
{6}    6.  p                              Assum. (1st Disj.)
{1,6}  7.  q                              3,6 MP
{1,6}  8.  p & q                          6,7 &I (1st Conc.)
{9}    9.  q                              Assum. (2nd Disj.)
{1,9}  10. p                              4,9 MP
{1,9}  11. p & q                          9,10 &I (2nd Conc.)
{1,5}  12. p & q                          5,6,8,9,11 ∨E
{1}    14. (p ∨ q) → (p & q)              5,12 CP
```

Here's the proof in the opposite direction:

```
{1}    1.  (p ∨ q) → (p & q)              Prem.
{2}    2.  p                              Assum.
{2}    3.  p ∨ q                          2 ∨I
{1,2}  4.  p & q                          1,3 MP
{1,2}  5.  q                              4 &E
{1}    6.  p → q                          2,5 CP
{7}    7.  q                              Assum.
{7}    8.  p ∨ q                          7 ∨I
{1,7}  9.  p & q                          1,8 MP
{1,7}  10. p                              9 &E
{1}    11. q → p                          7,10 CP
{1}    12. (p → q) & (q → p)              6,12 &I
{1}    13. p ↔ q                          12 ↔I
```

**Abbreviations:**

- &I = Conjunction introduction
- &E = Conjunction elimination
- ∨I = Disjunction introduction
- ∨E = Disjunction elimination
- ↔I = Double arrow introduction
- ↔E = Double arrow elimination
- MP = Modus ponens
- CP = Conditional proof (→ introduction)

Comment: What does Prem. Assum, VI, MP, EE, CP mean? Not familiar with that short-hand abbreviations.

Comment: I edited to show the abbreviations. EE should have been ∨E, so I made the correction.

Comment: @DavidConnor. I added a proof by means of identities as well.

Comment: You've yet to explain "Prem." and "Assum". Presumably, it's "premise" and "assuming"? Also, I assume "1,3 MP" on the right means "from 1. and 3., by Modus Ponens", but what does "{1,2}" on the left  mean?

Comment: Yes, "Prem." and "Assum."  mean premise and assumption. The numbers on the left show what each line is dependent upon. For example, {1,2} on line 4 of the second proof shows that that line depends on both the premise and the assumption. Both proofs end depending only on {1}, because there are rules which allow you to discharge assumptions. In these proofs, ∨E and CP are used to discharge them.

Comment: @DavidConnor. If you're interested in all these details, I recommend the book *[Logic](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Logic.html?id=MvdvuhxAgQIC&redir_esc=y)* by Paul Tomassi.